# Best way to deal with multiple API calls for same screen android

Tags: android, retrofit, android-volley

I have 10 API to call in same screen which are all independent and don't have any relation between each other.

exmp: In my screen i have different ui elements like recyclerview ,graphs,text view etc..

I need to call all api to show data what is the best way to do this is their any specific pattern available to achieve this.

Comment: Take a look at Retrofit's [Call.enqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101253/how-to-make-multiple-calls-with-retrofit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should maintain background thread concepts like **Asynktask,Worker manager,Rxjava** concepts to get response without any dependency to other API calls and faster execution asynchronously.