# How to make multiple requests using retrofit2 and rxjava2 on android?

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

In my android app, I want to make multiple http requests using retrofit and rxjava to fetch json data. The number of request depends on the user's preferences (1 up to 40). Each request is independent and returns same type. So, i tried to apply the way that is recommended in this question ([How to make multiple request and wait until data is come from all the requests in retrofit 2.0 - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474120/how-to-make-multiple-request-and-wait-until-data-is-come-from-all-the-requests-i)) which uses the zip function of rx-java. But i couldn't find a way to get and combine the results of each request. Response type that i used for single request in retrofit was `Response<List<NewsItem>>` where NewsItem is my custom object. (the response is json array actually but in a single request retrofit automatically handles it and converts it into list of my custom object) What i tried so far is below:

### My API Interface

```
public interface API {

    String BASE_URL = "xxx/";

    @GET("news/{source}")
    Observable<List<NewsItem>> getNews(@Path("source") String source);
}
```

### Viewmodel class to fetch data

```
public class NewsVM extends AndroidViewModel {

    public NewsVM(Application application){
        super(application);
    }

    private MutableLiveData<List<NewsItem>> newsLiveData;

    public LiveData<List<NewsItem>> getNewsLiveData(ArrayList<String> mySourceList) {

        newsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        loadNews(mySourceList);

        return newsLiveData;
    }

    private void loadNews(ArrayList<String> mySourceList) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

        API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

        //Gathering the requests into list of observables
        List<Observable<?>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String source: mySourceList){
            requests.add(api.getNews(source));
        }

        // Zip all requests
        Observable.zip(requests, new Function<Object[], List<NewsItem>>() {
            @Override
            public List<NewsItem> apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {

                // I am not sure about the parameters and return type in here, probably wrong 
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
        })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(
                new Consumer<List<NewsItem>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<NewsItem> newsList) throws Exception {

                        Log.d("ONRESPONSE",newsList.toString());
                        newsLiveData.setValue(newsList);
                    }
                },
                new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {

                        Log.d("ONFAILURE", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        ).dispose();

    }
}
```

It doesn't give error but doesn't give response also since I couldn't handle the response. Can anybody help me in combining the results of the each request? I've searched all the questions but can't find an example like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `Observable.from(Iterable<? extends T> iterable)` (`Observable.fromArray()` in rx-java2) instead of `zip`
So you'll have something like:

```
Observable.from(mySourceList)
    .flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<List<NewsItem>>>() {
        @Override
           public Observable<List<NewsItem>> call(String source) {
                return api.getNews(source);
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .toList() // This will give you List<List<NewsItem>>
        .map(new Func1<List<List<NewsItem>>, List<NewsItem>>() {
            @Override
            public List<NewsItem> call(List<List<NewsItem>> listOfList) {
                //Merged list of lists to single list using Guava Library
                List<NewsItem> list = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(listOfList));
                return list;
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<NewsItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<NewsItem> newsList) {
                //Attached the final newslist to livedata
                newsLiveData.setValue(newsList);
            }
        });
```

**EDITED** Updated the method

Comment: thanks @Boris but actually i am new in RxJava, it would be better you rewrite, and also my android studio doesn't supports lambas.

Comment: in case of Rx-java2 you can use `Flowable.fromIterable(mySourceList)` instead of `Observable.from(mySourceList)` :)

Comment: I've updated the method with the help of you (i've solved rx-java library problem) But now, when I debug, i see that it is not executing the .map method, so not working still.

Comment: @HuseyinSahin are you sure about `.unsubscribe()` at all? For me it looks strange to unsubscribe immediate after subscribe. Second question: are you sure that all `api.getGundemNews(source)` requests were executed? Cause `.toList` waits all items execution

Comment: I've put it later on, it was not working before either (when livedata takes the required items, it is safe to unsubscribe i think) but ok, i've removed it.

Comment: yes, unsubscribe is needed, but somewhere later, when you close the view for example

Comment: I'am not sure that all api.getNews(source) requests are executed, i don't know how to check it but another observation is the call function (under the flatmap) is executed (it enters the method) but when i log the source list in there, it gave me only one of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187670/discussion-between-boris-safonov-and-huseyin-sahin).

Answer (score 0):

`Object[] objects` is the array of items returned by the requests. Assuming that each of your request returns a `List<NewsItem>` and you wanted to combine all `NewsItem` into a single `List<NewsItem>`, I think you can do something along the lines of:

```
private void loadNews(ArrayList<String> mySourceList) {
    ...
    // Zip all requests
    Observable.zip(requests, new Function<Object[], List<NewsItem>>() {
        @Override
        public List<NewsItem> apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
            List<NewsItem> combinedNewsItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Object response : objects) {
                combinedNewsItems.addAll((List<NewsItem>) response);
            }
            return combinedNewsItems;
        }
    })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        ...
}
```

Be aware of the type casting.

Comment: Thanks @Sanlok, i've tried but didn't work. But it gives me some idea about how can I fill the method's inside. Also the casting that you suggest gives alert that `Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.List<NewsItem>` I think the issue is related to the response type. In single request that i made with Retrofit, retrofit generates it's raw response, which is type `Response<List<NewsItem>>`, then you can convert it to `List<NewsItem>` by using response.body method. But now i don't know what to do?

Comment: Can you tell us what you meant by "it didn't work"? Did it crash? Have you tried logging?

Comment: Also I am not sure what you meant by `Response<List<NewsItem>>` because your "My API Interface" says it returns an  `Observable<List<NewsItem>>`. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, in a single api call (which i used before) of course the api interface is this: `Call<List<NewsItem>>`. i mean  the response that retrofit returns is at type `Response<List<NewsItem>>` which may be the key factor. It didn't crashed when i tried your answer but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

If the **type of data** that you are getting is same ***List*** and the requests are multiple then you can use **Recursion Method to make 1 to n** requests and add data ***List*** on every success.

Comment: Thanks, it may be, but as i understand from your suggesstion it wouldn't be parallel which increases the return time.