# Trying ro use retrofit for pexels API im fresh

Tags: android, retrofit2

I dont have code , i want to get photos
id, url, phtographerName, src. https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation/
I want curated images and search images
I just want to understand how this works
Using retrofit ,
And how can i use 2 APIs in same project
What should i do in retrofitClient class
public retroClient() {

```
}

private static Retrofit getRetroClient() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static Api getApiService() {
    return getRetroClient().create(Api.class);
}
```

Comment: You'll get your answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474120/how-to-make-multiple-request-and-wait-until-data-is-come-from-all-the-requests-i